# hide scrollbar rails that appear by default around scrollable components that don't overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to hide the bars that appear around components whose content has not overflown (`overflow: scroll; max-width: ..etc.` )?

[image]

Comment: Without the HTML that reproduce that, no one would be able to help

Answer (score 1):

`overflow:auto` or `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` does the trick.
If you're sure the inner document or the element's content will not overflow. try using the `hidden` overflow property.

Comment: perfect, many thanks

Comment: @George if it fix the issue, you can accept his answer thanks to the check mark on the left